# Clean up the IDE tags

Tags: support, retag-request

IDE tags are often used as meta-tags, as additional information telling people what IDE the asker uses. It goes without saying, [meta-tags are a Bad Thing™.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) Now, these tags are not valid candidates for burnination, because the FAQ clearly states that on-topic includes

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

So they just need to be cleaned up. The worst offender, as I see it, is [Android plus Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+eclipse), and there's also [non-Android Java questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+netbeans+or+java+eclipse+-android). Those are the combinations I'm starting with. The questions that use the IDE as a meta-tag should have that tag removed.

For example,

[Does Eclipse need to build the project to do "Java Search"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581691/does-eclipse-need-to-build-the-project-to-do-java-search) -- Good use of both tags, both can stay.

[Google Maps works, but then displays gey tiles when drawing geopoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587121/google-maps-works-but-then-displays-gey-tiles-when-drawing-geopoints) -- Eclipse tag should be removed, has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I don't know about Eclipse, but Visual Studio versions can be quite important in answering C# and VB.NET questions.